# Merging files using git

Tags: git, github, merge

i have a question i have been trying to merge the same file but from different branches so lets imagine:
"number->" stands for the line number

file(branch1)

```
1->print("Hello world");
2->test();
```

file(branch2)

```
1->function1();
```

i would like to output of the merge to be like this
mergedfile

```
1->print("Hello world");
2->test();
3->function1();
```

Im using git and github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot force GIT to merge files as you imagine.

I suggest to:

```bash
git checkout branch1
git merge --no-commit branch2

# Review merged file on your own...

git add file
git commit
```

Comment: oh I see, thank you for the help btw, I will figure something out, doing this manually or something else